# how to show a the child of the selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm a beginner in jquery and i'm working on a menu. 
This is my list in html document:

```
    <ul>
    <li>
        <a class="entypo-menu" href="#"></a> <span class="menu">Menu ></span> 
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="entypo-star" href="#"></a> <span>Favorite</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="entypo-newspaper" href="#"></a> <span>About us</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="entypo-location" href="#"></a> <span>Find us</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="entypo-link" href="#"></a> <span>Share</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="entypo-help-circled" href="#"></a> <span>FAQ's</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and this is my js documment:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("span").hide();

$("li").click(function(){
    $("li span").show(20);
});});
```

this js code is showing all the 'span' of my html.
how can i show the 'span' of the clicked 'li' ?

Comment: Since you're just learning jQuery and no one mentioned it in their answer (all of which used it): once you've selected something, associated an event with it (`click` in this case) and run a callback function... `this` refers to the element that was acted upon.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [**.find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$("li").click(function(){
   $(this).find("span").show(20);
})
```

Comment: Why not use the `>` selector?

Comment: @rm-vanda How so?  The selector for `click()` should just be `li` as specified.  When inside the handler function, you only care about finding spans under currently clicked item, so I don;t see where you would use `>` selector in this case.

Comment: Good to know. Plus, when I commented that, I forgot you cannot do `$(this + "> child").` -- which is what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2):

like this

```
$("li").click(function(){
$(this).children("span").show(20);
});
```

Comment: `children()` will not work in this case, as the `<span>` element is two levels below the `<li>` and `children()` will only go down one level in the DOM tree.  The `find()` method proposed in other answer is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Why not use the `>` selector?

Comment: Yes I was wrong here, as when glancing at the HTML I didn't notice that the `<span>` is not nested in `<a>`. This method will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $(this).children('span').show(20);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mp7R3/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use children() then get 2nd children ,as 0th index ->1st child ,1st index -> 2nd child

```
$("li").click(function(){
   $(this).children().eq(1).show(20);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $("li").on("click", function () {
      $('li span').hide();
      $(this).find('span').show('20');
   });
```